# Non Zero Function .Differomophism.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $$f : S_1 → S_2$$ be a local diffeomorphism and let γ be a regular
curve on $S_1$. Show that $f ◦ γ$ is a regular curve on$ S_2$

Proof: $$d(f ◦ γ))/dt = Df(γ˙ (t))$$  is non-zero because γ˙ is non-zero (γ is regular)
and $Df$  is invertible

I dont understand why  those 2 conditions are enough for the derivative not to be zero.If the input of a function is non zero and the function is invertible why that makes the function non zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d(f\circ \gamma)/dt =Df_{\gamma(t)}d\gamma(t)/dt$.

$Df_{\gamma(t)}$ is the differential of $f$ at $\gamma(t)$ it is an invertible linear map $T{S_1}_{\gamma(t)}\rightarrow T{S_2}_{f(\gamma(t))}$ since $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, $d\gamma(t)/dt$ is a non zero element of $T{S_1}_{\gamma(t)}$, so if you take the image of a non zero vector by an invertible map, it is not zero.

Comment: i Understand why Df is invertible.I dont understand why if i take the image of a non zero vector it is not zero by an 1-1 function .Is it because it is a linear map? and only zero goes to zero?

Comment: because $Df$ is linear and invertible it's an isomorphism of groups and thus must take the identity to identity.